# crm: create unique invoice

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm-2011

Could you please help me with crm 2011
I need import invoice from another our system. (it is simple)

```
private void CreateInvoice(Invoice _invoice)
{
    IOrganizationService _service = GetCRMService();
    Entity entity = new Entity("invoice");

    entity[e_Invoice.InvoiceNumber] =  _invoice.Id.ToString();
    entity[e_Invoice.CustomerId] = new EntityReference("account", new Guid("6209A6AD-43B6-E211-A99D-005056A51C55"));

    _service.Create(entity);
}
```

I am call event on *PreRetriveInvoice*.

So on second call, method create another item (like **INV-01157-F4C5F5**)

For me this is unacceptable.

How I can check invoice number? Something like if I have this number in system, I'll skip the record.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create query to the `OrganizationService` asking to search for Invoice with given number and if result will be not empty — you skip creation of Invoice.

Your code might look like this:

```
private void CreateInvoice(Invoice _invoice)
{
    IOrganizationService _service = GetCRMService();

    // Getting all invoices with given number 
    var filter = new FilterExpression();
    filter.AddCondition(e_Invoice.InvoiceNumber, ConditionOperator.Equal, _invoice.Id.ToString());

    var query = new QueryExpression("invoice")
    {
        ColumnSet = new ColumnSet(true),
        Criteria = filter,
        Distinct = true
    };

    // Executing query
    var invoices = (EntityCollection)_service.RetrieveMultiple(query);

    if (invoices.Entities.Count == 0)
    {
        // Creating new invoice
        Entity entity = new Entity("invoice");

        entity[e_Invoice.InvoiceNumber] =  _invoice.Id.ToString();
        entity[e_Invoice.CustomerId] = new EntityReference("account", new Guid("6209A6AD-43B6-E211-A99D-005056A51C55"));

        _service.Create(entity);
    }
}
```